# Setting name attribute of symfony 2 form field

Tags: php, forms, symfony, formbuilder

How to set name attribute of rendered field in symfony 2?

Expected output:

```
     <input type="text" name="test" value="test" />
```

Rendering the field this way

```
     {{ form_widget(form.test, { 'attr': {'name': 'test'} }) }}
```

definitely does not work.

Output is still

```
     <input type="text" name="form[test]" value="test" />.
```

Is there any way to set the name attribute or id attribute dynamically? Thank you.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416783/symfony2-form-component-creating-fields-without-the-forms-name-in-the-name-att

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="form[test]" value="test" />
```

already has `test` as name. Of course there is still the root form name called `form` in your case. Removing this is not really recommended, because when you read the request to populate form data you can identify the form by its form name.

Read **[Form] Enable empty root form name** https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/2936

Answer (score 1):

overriding Twig block this way:

```
{% block widget_attributes -%}
id="{{ id }}"
{%- if read_only %} readonly="readonly"{% endif -%}
{%- if disabled %} disabled="disabled"{% endif -%}
{%- if required %} required="required"{% endif -%}
{%- for attrname, attrvalue in attr -%}
    {{- " " -}}
    {%- if attrname in ['placeholder', 'title'] -%}
        {{- attrname }}="{{ attrvalue|trans({}, translation_domain) }}"
    {%- elseif attrvalue is sameas(true) -%}
        {{- attrname }}="{{ attrname }}"
    {%- elseif attrvalue is not sameas(false) -%}
        {{- attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
name={{full_name}}
{%- endblock widget_attributes %}
```

The change is just moving  name={{full_name}} from the first line to the last one, so when you add the name attr to the form  builder add element, the name will be no longer ignored.

Comment: By default is the file "Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/view/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig"