# How to enable empty root form name (child form) when using inherit_data

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have applied the example in the symfony documentation to reduce Code Duplication with "inherit_data".

http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/inherit_data_option.html

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // ...

    $builder->add('foo', LocationType::class, array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Company'
    ));
}
```

It works good but when I use this exemple with a search form with **GET** method I get an url like this :

```
foo%5Baddress%5D=some+address&foo%5Bzipcode%5D=5000&foo%5Bcity%5D=paris&foo%5Bcountry%5D=france
```

and i'd like the url to be like this :

```
address=some+address&zipcode=5000&city=paris&country=france
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

You want a flat (non-nested) form field name. If you want to read the technical details, see [this issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2790) and this [pull request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/2936).

I found some examples [here](http://basit.me/change-input-name-of-the-form-fields-in-symfony3/). If you are using Symfony 2, [this example](https://www.jverdeyen.be/symfony2/symfony2-form-field-name/) would help too. I found two [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691021/setting-name-attribute-of-symfony-2-form-field) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416783/symfony2-form-component-creating-fields-without-the-forms-name-in-the-name-att).

## Solution 1: Create the form using createNamed method.

Create the form using `createNamed` method and set the first parameter (`$name`) to `null`:

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed(null, new MyFormType(), $dataObject, $formOptions);
```

## Solution 2: change your FormType

Alternatively, you can use the `getBlockPrefix` method of your `FormType` to set the name to `null`

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    ...

    /**
     * This will remove formTypeName from the form
     * @return null
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this works good with the baseFormType but not with the child form "LocationType".