# Symfony 3 - subform and element name

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I want to create form with composition pattern like this:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/inherit_data_option.html

I use Symfony 3.

and it's working. I have each element like single object and add this.

but finally my form elements names have name like

```
form[subform][element]
```

How to make flat structure without subform in name attribute?

```
use AppBundle\Base\Form\NickType;
use AppBundle\Base\Form\MailType;
use AppBundle\Base\Form\PassType;
use AppBundle\Base\Form\UserType;


class RegisterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nick', NickType::class)
            ->add('mail', MailType::class)
            ->add('password', PassType::class)
            ->add('repeat_password', PassType::class)
(etc...)
```

and SINGLE ELEMENT

```
class NickType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nick', TextType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'inherit_data' => true
        ));
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show your FormType.

Comment: @StephanVierkant I updated code. Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to define a `NickType` if it only inherits a TextType. You can remove `NickType`, `MailType`, etc.

You can just do:

```
class RegisterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nick', TextType::class)
        ;
(etc...)
```

If you want to reuse a form field, you have to create a [Custom Form Field Type](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html):

```
class NickType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            //...
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return TextType::class;
    }
}
```

You can remove `form[]` from the element name, but removing this is not really recommended, because when you read the request to populate form data you can identify the form by its form name. ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12706570/1405981))

> You can set the name of the root form to empty, then your field name
>   will be just form. Do so via

```
// the first argument to createNamedBuilder() is the name
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder(null, 'form', $defaultData)
    ->add('from', 'date', array(
        'required' => false,
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy'
    ));
```

([via](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13474522/1405981))

Comment: Yes but in future I will use nick element in many forms. 
It is reason why I want to have single object per fields. In one place I will have validation rules etc...

Comment: Ok its better but I got:
name="register[nick]"
Finally I want to get name="nick".
Thank you!

Comment: Is there is a specific reason you really want this? If it's only for the aesthetics or your code: please leave if this way. If there is another technical reason: please let us know, maybe there is a better solution. If you still want this: see my updated answer.

Comment: In another project we had many subforms and later we should use multidimensional array to receive data, and it is not good. So I think, it is main reason. I use Zend Framework every day and flat array is good to do $row->setFromArray($data); and later $row->save(); 
So it is reason why I want to do in this way in Symfony :) It is maybe habit. Thank you.

Comment: @taro Does my answer solve your question? If not, please let me know. Otherwise, consider upvoting and/or accepting my answer. I see you haven't cast any votes yet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote for more information.

Comment: yes it's works. Thank you. I want to vote your post and I will do it in future, but now I don't have enough points/reputation to do it.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I forgot that voting is only possible at 15+ rep.