# Symfony2.1 using form with method GET

Tags: url, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

I need help on using Symfony2.1 forms with method=GET and a clean URL space.

I am creating a "filter" which I'd like to set in the URL so that people can bookmark their links.

So, very simply the code:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
    ->add('from', 'date', array('required' => false, 'widget' => 'single_text', 'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy'))
```

I render the form widget and all is fine.

However when I submit the form, it produces very ugly GET parameters:

```
/app_dev.php/de/event?form%5Bfrom%5D=17.11.2012
```

This is because the input name is of course `form[from]`

So to clean the URL space, I made myself a theme:

```
{% block widget_attributes %}
{% spaceless %}
    id="{{ id }}" name="{{ id }}"{% if read_only %} disabled="disabled"{% endif %}{% if required %} required="required"{% endif %}{% if max_length %} maxlength="{{ max_length }}"{% endif %}{% if pattern %} pattern="{{ pattern }}"{% endif %}
    {% for attrname,attrvalue in attr %}{{attrname}}="{{attrvalue}}" {% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock widget_attributes %}
```

where I replaced `name="{{ full_name }}"` with `name="{{ id }}"`.

This works well - my URL space is cleaner:

```
/app_dev.php/de/event?form_from=17.11.2012
```

I guess I could live with that - although ideally `from=xxx` would be better. That is the first and more minor problem.

---

The second problem is that I can't get the form to bind anymore - this is obvious because the parameter "form" is no longer set - "form_from" has replaced it, but when you do a bind it is still expecting form[].

I tried to fix that like this:

```
$fromDate = $this->get('request')->query->get('form_from', null);
$request->query->set('form', array('from' => $fromDate);
```

But that doesn't work. I also suspect that I am digging a huge hole of hacks at the moment.

So, the question is: should I just live with the `form%5Bfrom%5D` url, or is there a better way to do all of this (without using POST obviously)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can set the name of the root form to empty, then your field name will be just `form`. Do so via

```
// the first argument to createNamedBuilder() is the name
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder(null, 'form', $defaultData)
    ->add('from', 'date', array(
        'required' => false,
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy'
    ));
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this when using FormTypes as services? I don't think you can access createNamedBuilder in that context and using FormType::getName() { return ''; } causes problems referencing the FormType as a service.

Comment: Of course you can access createNamedBuilder(), you just need to get access to the form factory :)

Comment: `$builder->getFormFactory()`... who knew? Thanks!

Comment: FormFactory -> `createNamed` could be used to get a `Form` instance instead of a builder

Comment: @caponica have you found a solution when using form as service ? I am stuck on this!

Comment: With the current version of form component, this will create a `form` tag with empty name attribute which doesn't validate as HTML5.

Answer (score 7):

old thread, but worth mentioning that symfony 3 ignores `getName` entirely.

However, you can do the same with `getBlockPrefix` if you need the form name to be blank.

```
public function getBlockPrefix() {
    return null;
}
```

this will result in form fields being named without a prefix.

Answer (score 2):

using `return null;` in your implementation of `AbstractType::getName` seems to have the same effect these days.

Comment: But if formtype returns null, is not possible to generate formType with dependency injection

Comment: Cannot use this approach with DI in general. Returning null is equivalent to the accepted answer, see for yourself.