# What is the recommended way to remove input name prefixes in symfony form

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

Say I have a form named `myform` with an input field named `myinput`. By default, symfony will generate HTML widget like:

```
<input name="myform[myinput]" ... >
```

This doesn't work with my current javascripts and I need to get the following instead:

```
<input name="myinput" ...>
```

I've searched quite a bit and found 2 ways to achieve this:

- return null in `getBlockPrefix()` method in form type class.
- create the form using `FormFactoryInterface::createNamed()` and pass `null` as name.

It seems like the first method is not recommended, since it would limit the ability to customize form rendering using prefixed blocks.

The 2nd method was recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416783/symfony2-form-component-creating-fields-without-the-forms-name-in-the-name-att) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384056/symfony2-1-using-form-with-method-get/13474522#13474522).

However both methods will change the name of the form to null and as a result symfony will generate the form like:

```
<form name="" ...>
```

This is probably because `form_div_layout.html.twig` looks like:

```
<form name="{{ name }}" ...
```

**Which doesn't validate as HTML5.**

According to [this page](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19818), "this is not a bug".

I know I can override the `form_start` block in the template and remove the name altogether, but it seems that the form wasn't designed to be used with null names in general (hence no check for name length in the template).

So my question is: What is the recommended and HTML5 compatible way to remove input name prefixes for symfony forms?

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug in form rendering. I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/26584) to symfony repo which was accepted.

Until the change is released, a temporary solution would be to add this code to your form theme:

```
{# fix HTML5 validation of forms with null names #}
{% block form_start %}
    {% set name = name|default(block_prefixes.1) %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Regarding PHP, I think either option is OK.
- Regarding Twig, I'd go for creating a custom form [theme](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes) and, optionally, [apply it to all forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#making-application-wide-customizations) on the site. I think that's the *Symfony way* of rendering a form according to your, specific, needs (nullable form name).