# FOSUserBundle change register form field names

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am developing an app using Symfony 2 and using FOSUserBundle. I would like to know if it is possible to define my own form with my own custom field names. I know the Symfony 2 Security Component allows you to map the field names for the login route but I don't know of a way to do so with the register form. I want to have fields like `name`, `email` instead of `fos_user_registration_form[email]` etc. Do I need to write a custom controller to handle the user registration or is there a configuration section in the firewall I can modify?

Comment: that kind of long fieldnames are common in symfony. I wonder why you want to have shorter names?

Comment: `fos_user_registration_form` is the name of the form in which the field `email` appears.  While it is possible to override the form to enable a shorter name it is hard to see what advantage this provides.  There is advantage in clearly identifying the form in which the field appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the FOSUserBundle configuration, set `fos_user.registration.form.name` value to `null` or empty string ([FOSUserBundle configuration reference](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration_reference.rst)).

Also see this question: [Symfony2 Form Component - creating fields without the forms name in the name attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416783/symfony2-form-component-creating-fields-without-the-forms-name-in-the-name-att)

Comment: The link to FOSUserBundle doc is broken